# Llamar mas de una vez metodo para llenar datagrid C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo un metodo para cargar datos a un datagrid, los datos son cargados uno a la vez.
El metodo es llamado desde dos puntos diferentes entonces cuando ya hay un fila cargada y el metodo es llamado desde otro punto se me borra la primer fila y se pone unicamente el dato que se cargo la ultima vez, no entiendo bien esto.

Desde este metodo mando llamar dos veces el metodo para llenar el datagrid:

```
 public void dataTressverify(string HexRFID)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    string horabef = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Column2"].Value);
                    string rfid = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Column3"].Value);
                    string claveup = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Column4"].Value);
                    if (rfid == HexRFID)
                    {
                        updateTime(format, claveup);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        getstaffdb(HexRFID);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                getstaffdb(HexRFID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Description...\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Como pueden ver llamo dos veces al metodo **getstaffdb(HexRFID)** y esto hace que se me borre la primer fila, lo que busco es que esta nueva fila se agregue debajo de la primera y asi sucesivamente.
Asi es como lleno el datagrid:

```
public void getstaffdb(string DataHex)
    {
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
          string query = "my query";
            comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {

                int addfile = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column1"].Value = Nombre;
                dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column2"].Value = datenow;
                dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column3"].Value = Hex;
                dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column4"].Value = id;

            }
            else
            {
        conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cosas raras que veo aca (sin probar tu error). Al metodo getstaffdb lo llamas tantas veces como filas haya en el grid. Estas tratando de modificar el grid dentro de un foreach, lo cual deberia causar error. El metodo add del grid ya agrega una fila, no recuerdo que devuelve, estas seguro que devuelve el numero de fila?

Comment: ¿Por qué no manipular la fuente de datos como un `IList` en lugar de directamente agregar filas/columnas al datagridview?

Comment: para que defines un parametro en `getstaffdb()` que nunca usas ?  Porque usas `ExecuteNonQuery()` y `ExecuteReader()` si vas a obtener regiostros elimina el primero

Comment: el ExecuteNonQuery() se fue de mas en este ejemplo, el ejemplo no tiene toda la informacion @LeandroTuttini no ponga las lineas donde se utiliza porque son inecesarias para lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aconsejaria estos cambios

Primero defines una clase que agrupen la informacion que obtienes de la consulta a la db

```
public class DataHexEntity
{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string datenow {get;set;}
    public string Hex {get;set;}
    public string id {get;set;}
}
```

El metodo `getstaffdb()` devolvera datos no accedera al grid agregando la row

```
public DataHexEntity getstaffdb(string DataHex)
{
    DataHexEntity entity = null;
    string query = "my query";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        entity =new DataHexEntity()
        {
            Nombre = reader["nombre"].ToString();
            datenow = reader["datenow"].ToString();
            Hex = reader["Hex"].ToString();
            id = reader["id"].ToString();
        };
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Por ultimo cada llamada se asigna a una lista temporal que iterasl al final para agregar las rows al grid

```
public void dataTressverify(string HexRFID)
{
    try
    {
        List<DataHexEntity> lista = new List<DataHexEntity>();

        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string horabef = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Column2"].Value);
                string rfid = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Column3"].Value);
                string claveup = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Column4"].Value);
                if (rfid == HexRFID)
                {
                    updateTime(format, claveup);
                }
                else
                {
                    var entity = getstaffdb(HexRFID);
                    if(entity != null)
                        lista.Add(entity);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var entity = getstaffdb(HexRFID);
            if(entity != null)
                lista.Add(entity);
        }

        foreach(var item in lista)
        {
            int addfile = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column1"].Value = item.Nombre;
            dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column2"].Value = item.datenow;
            dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column3"].Value = item.Hex;
            dataGridView1.Rows[addfile].Cells["Column4"].Value = item.id;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Description...\n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Es por eso que usas

```
var entity = getstaffdb(HexRFID);
if(entity != null)
    lista.Add(entity);
```

Para al final iteras los datos de los pasos previos que agregaron la info a la lista

```
foreach(var item in lista)
{
    int addfile = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    var row = dataGridView1.Rows[addfile];
    row.Cells["Column1"].Value = item.Nombre;
    row.Cells["Column2"].Value = item.datenow;
    row.Cells["Column3"].Value = item.Hex;
    row.Cells["Column4"].Value = item.id;
}
```